# Screensaver "kills" my GPU

Tags: linux, linux-mint, screensaver

Since a few upgrades I have a strange problem often (i.e.: more often than not, but not always) if I let my PC unattended long enough for it to completely shut off my graphics card it will not come up again.

A few more details:

- I have a fully up-to-date Linux Mint 20.1 "Ulyssa".
- Desktop is Cinnamon.
- My graphic card is an XFX Radeon RX 580
- I use a 4k Samsung "Smart TV" as monitor (HDMI).
- Cinnamon screensaver has  15min delay with no locks.
- Computer is still fully functional: I can (blindly) "CTRL-ALT-F1", login, "sudo halt" with expected results. I can restart the PC as normal
- Using "sudo reboot" *will* reboot the system, but it will *not* restore video.
- It seems video is restored by shutdown sequence because I see "LM" logo at shutdown, but not at restart.
- I see nothing relevant in /var/log/syslog (I can post the log, if useful).

What should I check?

### Update:

following @chris hint I logged-in via ssh and the only relevant entries in `dmesg` are:

```
[14631.434025] [drm:dce112_get_pix_clk_dividers [amdgpu]] *ERROR* dce112_get_pix_clk_dividers: Invalid parameters!!
[14631.434967] [drm:dm_restore_drm_connector_state [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Restoring old state failed with -22
```

These do not really mean much to me (my bad).
Can someone give further hints?

### Update2:

- Following further comments I tried with a normal PC monitor (not a smart TV), but behavior is the same.
- Issuing a `xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 3840x2160` from remote via `ssh -X me@host` results in "warning: output HDMI-A-0 not found; ignoring".
- Issuing the same command "blindly" from a text console ("CTRL-ALT-Fn") it fails with "Can't open display" which makes sense because I'm not under an Xserver in that  condition.
- I have no idea how to manage to start a program "blindly" in a graphic environment.

Please advise.

Comment: I had something sort of similar (but unlike your case, my problem did not survive a reboot, which is why this is just a comment) and would fix it by running an `xrandr` command that set up my screens as I wanted them. I assigned the command to a shortcut, so when my screen wouldn't wake up, I would use the shortcut and xrandr would sort it out. Now, since you say your issue persists after rebooting, I doubt this will help, but it could be worth trying.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks, I'll try it out. In my case I already noticed there's a huge difference in behavior between "reboot" and a full restart (e.g.: on restart BIOS doesn't seem to be involved at all, I see only GRUB menu) That may be worth another question, though.

Comment: @terdon: I'm a bit confused by xrandr CLI syntax; `xrandr --listmonitors` normally says "Monitors: 1 -- 0: +*HDMI-A-0 3840/1872x2160/1053+0+0  HDMI-A-0". What should I use to "set up my screens as I wanted them"? ;)

Comment: I would also suggest you try SSHing into the system when it's in that state and check out your dmesg log. I'd look for something along the lines of "GPU fell off the bus". I've seen it on some computers I administer.

Comment: @ZioByte try simply `xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --auto`. Or `xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 3840x2160`. Also, do you have a regular PC monitor to test with?

Comment: @Chris: I updated OP to reflect my findings.

Comment: @terdon: Themks I'll try next iteration. Yes, I do have a regular PC monitor, but it seems I have GPU problems (see updated OP).

Comment: It's still worth checking with the different monitor. I am thinking that this could be an issue specific to using the TV and/or to the fact that it is a 4k display. I'm clutching at straws, really, just trying to rule out possibilites. If it turns out you can't reproduce this with a "regular" PC monitor, that will help the debugging effort.

Comment: @terdon: please see my "Update2"

Comment: Well, crap. I think that means the screen isn't detectable. I wonder if unplugging it from the PC and plugging it back in would help it be detected again. But yes, this sounds more and more like a hardware issue, I think.